# apple style expanding search field in menu bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

I'm coding a website and I'm trying to replicate the effect on the [apple.com](http://www.apple.com/) where when you click to focus the search field in the menu bar, and the search field expands and the rest of the menu bar shrinks to accommodate it.

I've been trying various tricks with jquery kwicks, and also simply expanding a text field using the animate function in jquery but the effect is not the same. If someone could get me on the right track I'd very much appreciate it!

Best
Daniel

Comment: I was also finding the same apple style search box and found a very good one here..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305406/apple-style-expanding-searchfield

Answer (score 21):

this can be done by css only no need for javascript or anything...

```
#search input {
 width: 100px;
 -moz-transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
 -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
 transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
}
#search input:focus {
 width: 200px;
 -moz-transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
 -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
 transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

voila, thats it ;)

Comment: Thanks for such a nice and easy solution. I was doing this in jquery. Save lot of time and effort.

Comment: To cover more browsers (incl. down to IE9) also add:

-ms-transition: width .5s ease;
-o-transition: width .5s ease;

Comment: can someone make a fiddle for this? =)

Answer (score 3):

Taking a quick look at how Apple did it, it looks like their big move is this (I could be wrong - I'm rushing):

`#globalheader #globalnav li {
display: table-cell;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}`

This is a pretty unusual CSS display value, and clever on their part, forcing the `<li>`'s to work like `<td>`'s.  This means that changing the width of one of the "cells" causes the others in the same "row" to adjust how much room they take out.

**Long live (fake) table-based layout!**

So, assuming that CSS is possible for you, and I'm not off base with my quick glance at their code, your only task is to animate the width of the search box - the rest should follow suit.

Answer (score 1):

Not to over simplify things but what if in your css you float:right; this input box and then on focus you animate the box to the appropriate width like so:

CSS:

```
#inputtext{
    float:right;
    width:150px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("div#inputtext").focus(function(){
   $(this).animate({width:'300px'}, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a fiddle for this.
http://jsfiddle.net/MenuSo/r4xq9gz2/

HTML:

```
   <form id="expanding-form">
        <input type="text" id="expanding-input" placeholder="">
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
```

and CSS:

```
#expanding-form input{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    -o-transition: width .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: width .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
    transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
}
#expanding-form input:focus{
    width: 200px;
}
```

CSS would be enough.