# apple style expanding searchfield

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm trying to mimic apple's navbar style, specially the CSS3 expanding searchfield.

It uses an UL with display:table and it's LI's with display:table-cell and width:100%. When focused the search LI expands and the other LI's contract to fit.

Now my li's won't resize.

Anybody got a clue on what I'm missing there?

Also, IE is not even displaying anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey now you can used this one

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="search bar">
```

**css**

```
input[type="text"] {
    background: #444;
    border: 0 none;
    font: bold 12px Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;
    color: #d7d7d7;
    width:50px;
    padding: 6px 15px 6px 35px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    margin:3px 12px;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
    background:#fcfcfc;
    color: #6a6f75;
    width: 120px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    margin:3px 12px;
    outline: none;
}

input[type="text"] {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
}
```

live demo http://jsfiddle.net/vzLFS/3/

Comment: lol. What exactly have you done that is different from what I've done there in the live site? Because I've put some menu structure into your code and it works just fine. I'm pretty confused now:

http://jsfiddle.net/vzLFS/5/

Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 1):

On the apple page, they seem to add a class to the `nav`-element (`.searchmode`)when the input gets focused which handles the width of the `<li>`-element containg the `<input>`.

While not sure if there a css-only Solution for that you could do somehting like this with [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/) like this:

```
$('#searchform input').on('focus', function(){
   $(this).closest('li').css('width', '180px');
});

$('#searchform input').on('blur', function(){
   $(this).closest('li').css('width', '50px');
});
```

...and still use `css-transitions` for the FX :)

Comment: That's an option. Thanks. I'll struggle a bit more trying to make it css-only. Just a bit. hehe.